# i am getting error while running maven project on jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Console output on jenkins- 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project apportalautomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process

```
*Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.849 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-17T13:24:24+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/282M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project apportalautomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file D:\tejas PC\1MobilityFrameWork\1M_AP_Portal_Automation\testng_po.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:98)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Following is my pom file
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            4.0.0

```
        <groupId>apportalautomation</groupId>
        <artifactId>apportalautomation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>apportalautomation</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <!-- Source directory configuration -->
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng_po.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be usedfor compiling 
                    the code -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.53.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
                <version>3.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

following is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">

    <parameter name="appURL"
        value="https://ssg:*ssg!@123@ap58.smartsourcingglobal.net" />
    <parameter name="browserType" value="firefox" />

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.onemobility.apportal.utils.ScreenshotUtils" />
    </listeners>

    <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.LoginPageTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ForgotPasswordTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.DashboardTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationLocationTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationGroupsTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationEULATest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddGroupTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddLocationTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddEULATest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ReportsLoginHistoryTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationRolesTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddRoleTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationUsersTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddUserTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAppStoreTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.OrganizationAddAppTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ProfilesDeviceProfilesTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ReportsUserTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ReportsApplicationTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.ReportsDeviceTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.DIYUserPortalTest" />
            <class name="com.onemobility.apportal.tests.HelpPortalTest" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Comment: Do you have a file called `testng_po.xml`?

Comment: The problem seems to be as Jens has pointed out the testng_po.xml but can be because you do not have that file committed to the repository or because the filepath. As advice avoid using whitespaces, so changes the jenkins home or the checkout directory. If you want to see if your job is having only this problem or you do not have test try using as option in your maven invocation -DskipTests